# Loading button in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a login, I would like when the user put the credentials, the app show a toast or a image saying loading. But this image should be a few seconds in the screen before change the activity. Thanks.

Comment: i suggested you using https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs. has loading dialog or yourself implement loading dialog.

Comment: Have a look at the help on how to ask a good question, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the image is shown during the time when the app is doing authentication task or other works in background. I dont know why you want few seconds. And you can use **progress dialog** for the loading view.

Do authentication in an `AsyncTask` and update interface when data finishes loading.

You can start a new activity in your AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()` method.

You need a new class that extends AsyncTask:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  public MyTask(ProgressDialog progress) {
    this.progress = progress;
  }

  public void onPreExecute() {
    progress.show();
  }

  public void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
    //do your login here
  }

  public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    progress.dismiss();
  }
}
```

In activity do:

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setMessage("Loading...");
new MyTask(progress).execute();
```

In `onPostExecute()` start activity by `Intent`

```
   Intent go=new Intent(this.class,target_activity.class);
   startActivity(go);
```

Comment: Because firstly I want to create a mockup, is not a real login.